# Handling errors in MSAL Redirect - Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

We are currently trying to catch an error, when a user with a company Azure AD Account tries to access the application, but does not have access to the tenant where the application resides (Multi-tenant authorization has been setup on the app).

The user enters their credentials, and gets the below error when trying to login (which is the desired and expected behavior and which we are unable to capture):

[User Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzNnN.png)

The user has to cancel the authentication flow (as an automatic redirect back to the app does not occur on this error), which in turn does not allow us to capture that specific error (or any errors during the login process).

Is there a method we can utilize from either the MSAL Service or the Broadcast Service that will allow us to capture errors from the Azure Login Page (pictured above).

We've cloned the following repository from Microsoft to test error capturing during the login process (using clean, working code from a trusted source, which we confirmed works as intended):

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/redirects.md

We've found that the logging used in the MSAL Configuration (however verbose), does not actually capture the errors from the redirect flow. The closest we've come to capturing the error, was adding the below code to catch the BrowserAuthError (user_cancelled the flow) and logging it to the console.

```
try {
      await lastValueFrom(this.authService.ssoSilent(this.request));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      if (err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
          const loginResponse = this.authService.loginPopup(this.request).subscribe(
            {
              next: (response: AuthenticationResult) => {
                console.log(response)
              },
              error: (err2) => {
                console.log(err2)
                if(err2 instanceof BrowserAuthError){
                  console.log(
                    `CorrelationID: ${err2.correlationId}
                    errorCode: ${err2.errorCode}
                    errorMessage: ${err2.errorMessage}
                    message: ${err2.message}
                    name: ${err2.name}`)
                }},
              complete: () => {
                console.log("Completed")
              }
            }
          )
      } else {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
```

This is the outcome in the Console:

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP7ON.png)

Some other things we've tried with little success:

- Tried using handleRedirectPromise method
- Tried using handleRedirectObservable method
- Tried using msalSubject$ observable on the MSAL Broadcast Service
- Tried using InProgress$ observable on the MSAL Broadcast Service

None of which yielded the expected results.

If more detail is required, we can post whatever is necessary directly in the comments.

Just to re-iterate, we want to capture the error before the user cancels the flow, and return that error, as well as the user back to the app for a seamless login experience.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The [User Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzNnN.png) is thrown by the AAD service in the domain `login.microsoftonline.com` which is out of MSAL JS's execution scope. Since we redirect to the AAD domain when the token is requested, any errors that happen before they can redirect to MSAL JS (in this case the app domain) are displayed to the user and not sent back as an error response. There is no MSAL JS or app running at the time in the stack and hence we timeout instead as we do not get the response back in time.

This is why even enabling verbose logs for MSAL JS does not capture this error. There are only a bunch of errors that are sent back to the app domain (e.g., InteractionRequired - since this would need user i/p and can be recovered).

I checked with the service team if there is a way to capture this error in the stack and the only time they would return this would be if `prompt=none` i.e., silent cases.

Comment: Thank you @sameerag, i was hoping there would be a way to capture this but if there isnt, thats completely understandable. Im new to Angular (sort of, been working on it for 6 months) but some concepts im still trying to understand. Thank you for the detailed answer